# Single Sign on for multiple projects in ASP.net Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis

I'm trying to develop many projects under one solution on asp.net and I want to be authenticated just on the first project (Demarrage) then having authenticated immedialtly in the others projects. I'm using Windows authentication.[Project Overview Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nJGr.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [tour] and [ask]. You're supposed to show what you have tried. Single Sign On in ASP.NET is thoroughly documented all over the web; what have you found?

Comment: I want to know how to implemante this single sign on on my case

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you enable the IIS windows auth and use IE or Chrome to access the web application. The browser will auto store the windows credenticial and use it to login in. That means you just need to login in once and it could access other web application.

If you want to enable a SSO for both windows auth and other auth mode. I suggest you could consider using identity server. The Identity server is an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework. It could Single sign-on (and out) over multiple application types and it support windows auth.

Details about how to use it with windows auth, you could refer to below article:

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/windows.html

Comment: Hi Brando, first of all, thank u for your answer...for the first part of your answer it happend just when browser allow you to store cookies ...for the second part I'll read details about this article, it look very important. Thank u for all